# Minecraft fossils in the overworld?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can fossils be found in the over world (Similarly to the way they do in the soul valley biome of the nether) and what is the spawn rate of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they do spawn in the overworld, but only in certain biomes, and (by rule of thumb) only underground.

> Fossils randomly generate y-coordinates 40 to 49 underground in the Overworld (deserts, swamps, and their variants). Each chunk has a 1⁄64 chance to generate a fossil.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fossil#Generation)

For comparison, [Nether Fossils](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Fossil) that spawn in Soul Sand Valleys have different generation and structures